# jquery fullcalendar with update event not able to update class

Tags: jquery, class, fullcalendar

I am not able to update class while update event in fullcalendar. please help me to update class at time of update events i have mention condition also for this.

```
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {

           $("#calEventDialog").dialog("option", "buttons", [
            {
            text: "Save",
               click: function() {

             if($('#calEventDialog #eventTitle').val() == "Avilable"){
                eventClass = "avilable";
                }
                else {
                 eventClass = "unavilable";
                }

               calEvent.title =$('#calEventDialog #eventTitle').val();
               calEvent.start =$('#calEventDialog #eventStart').val();
               calEvent.end =$('#calEventDialog #eventEnd').val();
               calEvent.eventClass =eventClass;
               alert(eventClass);
               $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);

});
```

is there any suggestion for this ?

Comment: why are you using select event can you please specify

Comment: Because, I am generating popup on click and in that popup i have set date-piker. so first time click event will and and second time on click on same event it will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing it the way you have it try this.

> `select` is a callback that will fire after a selection is made.
>
> `eventClick` is Triggered when the user clicks an event.

For creating an event you should use `select` and for updating an event you should use `eventClick`. You are using `calEvent` where does it come from it is a part of `eventClick`, your code should be something like this.

```
select: function( startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent, view ) {
   //create and save new event
   //here you use 
   //your dialog goes here
   var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
   copiedEventObject.title =$('#calEventDialog #eventTitle').val();
   copiedEventObject.start =$('#calEventDialog #eventStart').val();
   copiedEventObject.end =$('#calEventDialog #eventEnd').val();
   copiedEventObject.eventClass =eventClass;
   $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject);
},
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
   //here you will get calEvent
   //make necessary changes and update this event.
   //your dialog goes here
   calEvent.title =$('#calEventDialog #eventTitle').val();
   calEvent.start =$('#calEventDialog #eventStart').val();
   calEvent.end =$('#calEventDialog #eventEnd').val();
   calEvent.eventClass =eventClass;
   $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
}
```

Comment: the calendar event `calEvent ` is a part of `eventClick` not `select: fn` the asker has used `calEvent ` but where is it comming from thats the question.